# Debian 9: Backlight Brightness

Tags: debian, boot, system-installation, monitors, brightness

I've just installed a fresh new Debian 9 with LXDE into an ACER AMD Notebook and everything seems to be working fine, except for the backlight brightness. During the boot, it happens the following:

- several [messages and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBmDp.jpg) appear

  ```
  [FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
  See 'systemctl status systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service' for details.
  Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0
  ...
  [ OK ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0
  ```
- often backlight brightness is reset to max

In order to set the backlight brightness to an acceptable level, the best solution so far seems to be opening a terminal and typing the command line below as soon as Debian initialize:

- `tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness <<< 15`

**Questions**

1. How to avoid the backlight brightness being reset to max during the boot?
2. How to set shortcuts to the backlight brightness (ex: `[Fn] + ←/→`)?

---

**Debug**

```
root@debian:~# dmesg | grep -i "error\|firmware\|backlight"
[    1.049855] pci 0000:01:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
[    7.729996] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   12.960474] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/PALM_pfp.bin
[   13.017938] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/PALM_me.bin
[   13.043827] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
[   13.161157] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
[   13.897112] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
```

```
root@debian:~# systemctl status systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
● systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-06-16 06:37:19 -03; 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-backlight@.service(8)
  Process: 411 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight load backlight:acpi_video0 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 411 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 16 06:37:19 debian systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
Jun 16 06:37:19 debian systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 16 06:37:19 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Jun 16 06:37:19 debian systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 16 06:37:19 debian systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

---

**Hardware Specifications**
[Notebook Aspire E1-421-0622](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4095) | [product details](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2013/4876/E1-421/NX.M25AL.004.html)

- AMD 2 Core™ Processor E1-1200 (1.4 GHz) 1MB Cache 64-bit Processing
- AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics Controller
- 2Gb DDR3 SDRAM Memory
- 256MB shared video memory

**Debian Strech**
[debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso)

- Small CDs
- AMD64 processor architecture
- Non-free package `firmware-amd-graphics` installed
  [radeon kernel modesetting for R600 or later requires firmware-amd-graphics](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/8nz4pw/error_radeon_kernel_modesetting_for_r600/)
- Software selection
  (  ) Debian desktop environment
  (  ) ... GNOME
  (  ) ... Xfce
  (  ) ... KDE
  (  ) ... Cinnamon
  (  ) ... MATE
  (X) ... LXDE
  (  ) web server
  (X) print server
  (  ) SSH server
  (X) standard system utilities

Answer (score 3):

Your system seems to have two interfaces for backlight control: `backlight:acpi_video0` and `backlight:radeon_bl0`. And apparently the ACPI interface does not work, and/or causes problems when used together with the Radeon-specific interface.

Since the Radeon-specific interface seems to work fine, I'd try telling systemd to stop using the ACPI backlight interface first:

```
systemctl mask systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
```

If necessary, this can be undone with:

```
systemctl unmask systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
```

If this does not help, further investigation is needed.

With `journalctl -xb` you should be able to see a quite verbose version of messages *for the current boot only*. By default, persistent storage of systemd journal is not enabled in Debian 9, but it's quite easy to enable: just run `mkdir /var/log/journal` as root. Then, starting from next boot, the journal will be stored persistently and you will be able to e.g. view the log of the previous boot from startup to shutdown with `journalctl -xb -1`. The oldest logs will eventually be automatically purged, controlled by `journald`'s configurable criteria for available disk space.

Comment: I've just tried the `systemctl mask`. The only noticeable difference is that most of the [messages and errors](https://imgur.com/a/r3e8RVM) disappeared. But, besides that, the other issues are quite the same: strong backlight flash during boot, backlight brightness is often reset to max and there no shortcut is available.

Comment: I've also posted a [partial solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450202/291825). Let me know your comments.

Comment: Just tested `journalctl -xb` and, indeed, there is a lot of verbose in it. However, it is not in a 'friendly' manner compared to [messages and errors](https://imgur.com/a/r3e8RVM). It seems awkward to me having to take a picture of the screen in order to capture the messages and errors during boot.

Answer (score 2):

Open file `/etc/default/grub` and update the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

To line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=video"
```

Then run:

```
update-grub
reboot
```

Possible alternative parameters case this one doesn't work (complete discussion at [Kernel command-line options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#Kernel_command-line_options)):

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
acpi_backlight=none
```

In my case, `acpi_backlight=video` seems to have solved both issues:

- backlight brightness is no longer resetting to max during boot (question 1)
- `[Fn] + ←/→` was set as shortcut for decrease/increase backlight brightness (question 2)

After that there was a conflict with the shortcut `[Fn] + ←`, which was decreasing the backlight brightness but also opening the Display Settings window. Just opened `Preferences > Setup Hot Keys` and changed the 'obscure' Hotkey `XF86Display` to something else.

Comment: It is good if setting `acpi_backlight=video` worked, but this option means that acpi will use its default driver, ie, `video.ko` [Ref.: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt]. 

As @telecoM rightly said, having both `acpi_video0` and `radeon_bl0` in `/sys/class/backlight` means that there are two interfaces for backlight control and one needs to be turned off. 

Since I too was facing the same issue, I went on with `acpi_backlight=native` option to let only radeon control backlight. And sure enough the brightness reset issue was gone.